# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.IsFile Returns False When Url is ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I'm hitting a local URL of the form: `http://localhost/example.dev/eu/default.aspx.`

My goal is to determine when the request is an aspx file inside of the global.asax file, and subsequently do stuff if it is an aspx file (and only an aspx file) using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.IsFile
```

It's consistently resolving to `false` however and I'm not sure why. My complete `global.asax` code is:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.IsFile)
{
    if(File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath))
    {
        if(new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath).Extension.Equals("aspx"))
        {
            DoSomethingWithThePagesURL();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here for some helpful stuff.. http://wdevs.blogspot.com/2009/03/url-properties-of-request-to-aspnet.html

Answer (score 4):

Did you take a look at the [Documentation for IsFile Property?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.isfile).  It seems very clear from the documentation that `Http:` is not `File:`.

> The IsFile property is true when the Scheme property equals UriSchemeFile.

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VgD6n)

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Uri uriAddress2 =  new Uri("file://server/filename.ext");
    Console.WriteLine(uriAddress2.LocalPath);
    Console.WriteLine("Uri {0} a UNC path", uriAddress2.IsUnc ? "is" : "is not");
    Console.WriteLine("Uri {0} a local host", uriAddress2.IsLoopback ? "is" : "is not");
    Console.WriteLine("Uri {0} a file", uriAddress2.IsFile ? "is" : "is not");
  }
}
```

Results:

> \server\filename.ext
>
> Uri is a UNC path
>
> Uri is not a local host
>
> Uri is a file

Answer (score 0):

I use Nuget package walter.web.firewall that inject a IPageRequest in each request, this contains access to the requests underlying resource and will provide access via IPageRequest.LocalFile

However if you do need a firewall and it has been a while since this was asked, and lot's of framework changes have taken place since the question was asked so let my try and answer it in a way that uses no framework classes hoping it will work for all that try and implement it in the future.

here's the code:

```
public enum FileLocation
{
    NotSet,
    Disk,
    Resource,
}

private static readonly string[] FileExtenstions = new[] {
    ".js"
    ,".ts"
    ,".vue"
    ,".css"
    ,".jpg"
    ,".png"
    ,".gif"
    ,".ico"
    ,".svg"
    ,".ttf"
    ,".eot"
    ,".ttf"
    ,".woff"
    ,".woff2"
    ,".mp4"
    ,".mp3"
    ,".emf"
};

public FileLocation IsMappedTo(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));
    }
    //make sure we support .net default URI contract
    if (uri.IsFile)
        return FileLocation.Disk;

    //now assume you are looking in a web application
    var path = uri.AbsolutePath;
    if (path.Length == 0 || path.Equals("/",StringComparison.Ordinal) || path.Length< FileExtenstions.Min(s=>s.Length))
        return FileLocation.NotSet;

    //get the directory normally one would use IWebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath different versions .net will have other methods
    var dir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");

    //get all resources names from the assembly hosting this class out side if the loop from this assembly you can also use
    //you can also use GetManifestResourceNames() to use the web application's assembly
    var resourceNames = new HashSet<string>(this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames());
    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    if (entryAssembly != null && entryAssembly != this.GetType().Assembly)
    {
        foreach (var entry in entryAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry))
                resourceNames.Add(entry);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < FileExtenstions.Length; i++)
    {
        if (FileExtenstions[i].Equals(path[FileExtenstions[i].Length..], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || path.Contains(FileExtenstions[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //exists on disk
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, path.Replace("/", @"\"))))
                return FileLocation.Disk;

            //has a file as an embedded resource with the same name (ignores the path) so you might have duplicates names
            if (resourceNames.Any(a => a.EndsWith(path.Split('/')[^1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                return FileLocation.Resource;
        }
    }

    return FileLocation.NotSet;
}
```